# Javascript object key by element id? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This looks like a very simple issue, but I just can't get it to work.

I have a Javascript object like this:

```
var person = {};
person.one = {gender: 'male', name: 'John'};
person.two = {gender: 'male', name: 'Doe'};
person.three = {gender: 'female', name: 'Jane'};
```

Then I have some HTML like so:

```
<a id="one">click</a>
<a id="two">click</a>
<a id="three">click</a>
```

Now, I need to get the correct object value by the id of the clicked link. So basically, I need to dynamically access the 1st-level object keys without a for-loop, since the keys are strings.

I've tried this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   alert(person[$(this).attr('id')['gender']]);
});
```

It didn't work. Neither did this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   alert(person.($(this).attr('id')).gender);
});
```

All I get back is an "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression". Obviously, my syntax is way off.

I've already read through many posts on here, but couldn't find the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: your first example didnt work because you put the first closing brace in the wrong place. `person[$(this).attr('id')]['gender']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a property with a dynamic name like you're going for, the correct syntax is to use brackets, like an array.

```
alert(person[$(this).attr('id')].gender);
```

Or it might just be cleaner-looking to pull that ID into a separate variable:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
alert(person[id].gender);
```

Your call :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   alert(person[$(this).attr('id')]['gender']);
});
```

You had your square brackets in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2):

Try `alert(person[$(this).attr('id')].gender)`